# How to make a instruction if a condition is made inside a while loop - Liberty Basic

Tags: basic

I have been trying to figure out how to make a Notice box appear when the while loop reaches 3.

I'am using a programing language called [Liberty BASIC](http://www.libertybasic.com/faq.html#1) (v4.5.1). Basic is used for creating programs for all verisions of windows including 64-bit. Liberty Basic is a simplified programign language for begginers.

Basic fetures: GUI, Debugger, a editor and compiler.

My code->problem:

```
X = 1
WHILE X < 5
    PRINT "Number "; X
    IF X=3 THEN  EXIT WHILE  'how to insert a working NOTICE "We have reached the number 3";
    X = X + 1
WEND
END
```

I have found out what my problem was. The order in whitch i written my code was wrong. I exited the while loop before writing a NOTICE message so it was never written. 
I am sory for not providing enough information to solve the problem.

My code->solved:

```
PRINT "Stoping and exiting a while loop when X becomes 3"
X=1
WHILE X<5
    PRINT "Number: "; X
    X = X + 1
    IF X = 3 THEN
        NOTICE "While has reached 3, so we stopped"
        EXIT WHILE
    END IF
WEND
END
```

Comment: Since Liberty Basic is not even a tag, it would seem there are not many people who would be able to answer this question with any certainty, including me.  Is this a windows basic or a dos-based one?  Are you talking about a standard windows message box?  I don't know of any dialects of basic that support "exit while"  Perhaps if you can provide us with more information?

Comment: I have edited the question, sory for explaning it bad I hope it is better now.

Comment: Liberty Basic was created using SmallTalk which makes it quite unique in the BASIC world.